# Restarting HP 1810 without writable SNMP?

Tags: networking, hp, snmp, automation, hp-procurve

I have been tasked with finding a way to reboot all of my switches for a bunch of small satellite sites every night when everyone is gone. I have HP 1810-26G switches at most of the sites, which is fine and dandy when they work. We're needing to restart them at a few sites a month, which results in users being mad, and my boss being mad. The 1810's are bottom of the barrel but we're stuck with them now. They have port 80 open, and that's it. They are read only SNMP, no SSH, no Telnet, no serial. I have no idea how to accomplish this task.

Since they're read only, I can't use one of the MIBs to set the switch to reboot. No SSH, no Telnet means I can't script the reboot. I guess I could tell the UPS to stop and start the outlet every night, but that's just not feasible. What are my options? Since we're handling a number of small sites, several thousand for management software isn't really feasible either.

I've tried snmp, got no where. Without any remote access ability, I am out of things to try.

Answer (score 1):

Rebooting the switches periodically is the wrong fix for this. Your real goal is to stop the devices from locking-up, not finding a way to reboot them remotely.

I suggest upgrading the firmware for the switches. HP ProCurve 1810 switches were impacted by a bug that would cause them to stall and require a reset.

> IP Communication (CR_0000131152) - Some clients connected directly to
>   the switch become unable to communicate on the network. When this
>   happens, the switch log shows Unable to delete FDB entry messages.

Go to [HP's support site](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/drivers.html) and enter your specific product number. You'll find link to the current firmware. This will likely solve the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: Switches are the most recent firmware according to the Support site. I really wish we'd stop putting these half assed managed switches out :(

Comment: I'm sorry. I do have plenty of this model in production, and aside from the corrected issue noted above, they've been incredibly solid.